# mongoid search in an array inside an array of hash

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

Say `Object embeds_many searched_items`

Here is the document:

```
{"_id": { "$oid" : "5320028b6d756e1981460000" },

"searched_items": [
{
  "_id": { "$oid" : "5320028b6d756e1981470000" },
   "hotel_id": 127,
  "room_info": [
    {
       "price": 10,
      "amenity_ids": [
        1,
        2
      ]
    },
    {
      "price": 160,
      "amenity_ids": null
    }
  ]
  },
  {
  "_id": { "$oid" : "5320028b6d756e1981480000" },
  "hotel_id": 161,
  "room_info": [
    {
      "price": 400,
      "amenity_ids": [4,5]
    }
   ]
  }
 ] 
}
```

I want to find the "searched_items" having `room_info.amenity_ids` IN [2,3].

I've tried

`object.searched_items.where('room_info.amenity_ids' => [2, 3])`

`object.searched_items.where('room_info.amenity_ids' =>{'$in' => [2,3]}`

with no luck

Answer (score 5):

mongoid provides **elem_match** method for searching within objects of Array Type

e.g.

```
class A
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :some_field, type: Array
end

A.create(some_field: [{id: 'a', name: 'b'}, {id: 'c', name: 'd'}])

A.elem_match(some_field: { :id.in=> ["a", "c"] }) => will return the object
```

Let me know if you have any other doubts.

**update**

```
class SearchedHotel
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :hotel_id, type: String
  field :room_info, type: Array
end

SearchedHotel.create(hotel_id: "1", room_info: [{id: 1, amenity_ids: [1,2], price: 600},{id: 2, amenity_ids: [1,2,3], price: 1000}])
SearchedHotel.create(hotel_id: "2", room_info: [{id: 3, amenity_ids: [1,2], price: 600}])

SearchedHotel.elem_match(room_info: {:amenity_ids.in => [1,2]})

Mongoid::Criteria
 selector: {"room_info"=>{"$elemMatch"=>{"amenity_ids"=>{"$in"=>[1, 2]}}}}
 options:  {}
 class:    SearchedHotel
 embedded: false
```

And it returns both the records. Am I missing something from your question/requirement. If yes, do let me know.

Comment: Say I have this:

`A.create(some_field: [{id: 'a', name: 'b', tag_ids: [1,2,3]}, {id: 'c', name: 'd'},  tag_ids: [2,3, 4]])`

Now I want to find the object having `some_field.tag_ids.include?(2,3)`

Comment: Obj 1 -> A.create(some_field: [{id: 'a', name: 'b', tag_ids: [6,7,8]}, {id: 'c', name: 'd'},  tag_ids: [5,6,7]])
Obj 2 -> A.create(some_field: [{id: 'a', name: 'b', tag_ids: [1,2,3]}, {id: 'c', name: 'd'},  tag_ids: [2,3, 4]])

==> A.elem_match(some_field: { :tag_ids.in=> [2,3,4] }) will return object 2 only and not the first one

Comment: Here is the document:

`[#<SearchedHotel _id: 53253c246d756e49a7030000, hotel_id: \"1\", room_info: [{\"id\"=>1, \"amenity_ids\"=>[1, 2], \"price\"=>600}, {\"id\"=>2, \"amenity_ids\"=>[1, 2, 3], \"price\"=>1000}]>, #<SearchedHotel _id: 53253c246d756e49a7040000, hotel_id: \"2\",  room_info: [{\"id\"=>3, \"amenity_ids\"=>[1, 2], \"price\"=>600}]>]`

Here is the criteria:

`"#<Mongoid::Criteria\n  selector: {\"room_info\"=>{\"$elemMatch\"=>{\"amenity_ids\"=>{\"$in\"=>[1, 2]}}}}\n  options:  {}\n  class:    SearchedHotel\n  embedded: true>\n"`

returns nothing

Answer (score 0):

It's important to distinguish between top-level queries sent to the MongoDB server and
client-side operations on embedded-documents that are implemented by Mongoid.
This is the underlying confusion between the original question and the answer from @sandeep-kumar and associated comments.
The original question is all about the where clause on embedded documents after the query result has already been fetched.
The answer @sandeep-kumar and comments are all about top-level queries.

The following test covers both, showing how answers from @sandeep-kumar do work on the examples in your comments,
and also what does and does not work on your original question.
To summarize, Sandeep's answers do work for top-level queries.
Please review your code, if there are remaining problems, please post the exact Ruby code that summarizes the problem.

For your original question, please note that "object" has already been fetched from MongoDB,
and that you can verify this by looking at the log/test.log file.
The subsequent "where" operations are all client-side execution by Mongoid.
Simple "where" clauses do work at the embedded document level.
Complex "where" clauses involving nested array values don't seem to work -
I didn't really expect Mongoid to reimplement '$in' on the client-side.
Knowing that the "object" already has the query result,
and that the association "searched_items" gives you convenient access to the embedded documents,
you can write Ruby code to select what you want as in the following test.

Hope that this helps.

test/unit/my_object_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'pp'

class MyObjectTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    MyObject.delete_all
    A.delete_all
    SearchedHotel.delete_all
  end

  test "original question with client-side where operation on embedded documents" do
    doc = {"_id"=>{"$oid"=>"5320028b6d756e1981460000"}, "searched_items"=>[{"_id"=>{"$oid"=>"5320028b6d756e1981470000"}, "hotel_id"=>127, "room_info"=>[{"price"=>10, "amenity_ids"=>[1, 2]}, {"price"=>160, "amenity_ids"=>nil}]}, {"_id"=>{"$oid"=>"5320028b6d756e1981480000"}, "hotel_id"=>161, "room_info"=>[{"price"=>400, "amenity_ids"=>[4, 5]}]}]}
    MyObject.create(doc)
    puts
    object = MyObject.first
    <<-EOT.split("\n").each{|line| puts "#{line}:"; eval "pp #{line}"}
    object.searched_items.where('hotel_id' => 127).to_a
    object.searched_items.where(:hotel_id.in => [127,128]).to_a
    object.searched_items.where('room_info.amenity_ids' => {'$in' => [2,3]}).to_a
    object.searched_items.where('room_info.amenity_ids'.to_sym.in => [2,3]).to_a
    object.searched_items.select{|searched_item| searched_item.room_info.any?{|room_info| room_info['amenity_ids'] && !(room_info['amenity_ids'] & [2,3]).empty?}}.to_a
    EOT
  end

  test "A comment - top-level queries" do
    A.create(some_field: [{id: 'a', name: 'b', tag_ids: [6,7,8]}, {id: 'c', name: 'd'}, tag_ids: [5,6,7]])
    A.create(some_field: [{id: 'a', name: 'b', tag_ids: [1,2,3]}, {id: 'c', name: 'd'}, tag_ids: [2,3,4]])
    puts
    pp A.where('some_field.tag_ids'.to_sym.in => [2,3]).to_a
    pp A.elem_match(some_field: { :tag_ids.in => [2,3,4] }).to_a
  end

  test "SearchedHotel comment - top-level query" do
    s = <<-EOT
      [#<SearchedHotel _id: 53253c246d756e49a7030000, hotel_id: \"1\", room_info: [{\"id\"=>1, \"amenity_ids\"=>[1, 2], \"price\"=>600}, {\"id\"=>2, \"amenity_ids\"=>[1, 2, 3], \"price\"=>1000}]>, #<SearchedHotel _id: 53253c246d756e49a7040000, hotel_id: \"2\",  room_info: [{\"id\"=>3, \"amenity_ids\"=>[1, 2], \"price\"=>600}]>]
    EOT
    a = eval(s.gsub('#<SearchedHotel ', '{').gsub(/>,/, '},').gsub(/>\]/, '}]').gsub(/_id: \h+, /, ''))
    SearchedHotel.create(a)
    puts
    <<-EOT.split("\n").each{|line| puts "#{line}:"; eval "pp #{line}"}
    SearchedHotel.elem_match(room_info: {:amenity_ids.in => [1,2]}).to_a
    EOT
  end
end
```

$ ruby -Ilib -Itest test/unit/my_object_test.rb

```
Run options:

# Running tests:

[1/3] MyObjectTest#test_A_comment_-_top-level_queries
[#<A _id: 5359329d7f11ba034b000002, some_field: [{"id"=>"a", "name"=>"b", "tag_ids"=>[1, 2, 3]}, {"id"=>"c", "name"=>"d"}, {"tag_ids"=>[2, 3, 4]}]>]
[#<A _id: 5359329d7f11ba034b000002, some_field: [{"id"=>"a", "name"=>"b", "tag_ids"=>[1, 2, 3]}, {"id"=>"c", "name"=>"d"}, {"tag_ids"=>[2, 3, 4]}]>]
[2/3] MyObjectTest#test_SearchedHotel_comment_-_top-level_query
    SearchedHotel.elem_match(room_info: {:amenity_ids.in => [1,2]}).to_a:
[#<SearchedHotel _id: 5359329d7f11ba034b000003, hotel_id: "1", room_info: [{"id"=>1, "amenity_ids"=>[1, 2], "price"=>600}, {"id"=>2, "amenity_ids"=>[1, 2, 3], "price"=>1000}]>,
 #<SearchedHotel _id: 5359329d7f11ba034b000004, hotel_id: "2", room_info: [{"id"=>3, "amenity_ids"=>[1, 2], "price"=>600}]>]
[3/3] MyObjectTest#test_original_question_with_client-side_where_operation_on_embedded_documents
    object.searched_items.where('hotel_id' => 127).to_a:
[#<SearchedItem _id: 5359329d7f11ba034b000006, hotel_id: 127, room_info: [{"price"=>10, "amenity_ids"=>[1, 2]}, {"price"=>160, "amenity_ids"=>nil}]>]
    object.searched_items.where(:hotel_id.in => [127,128]).to_a:
[#<SearchedItem _id: 5359329d7f11ba034b000006, hotel_id: 127, room_info: [{"price"=>10, "amenity_ids"=>[1, 2]}, {"price"=>160, "amenity_ids"=>nil}]>]
    object.searched_items.where('room_info.amenity_ids' => {'$in' => [2,3]}).to_a:
[]
    object.searched_items.where('room_info.amenity_ids'.to_sym.in => [2,3]).to_a:
[]
    object.searched_items.select{|searched_item| searched_item.room_info.any?{|room_info| room_info['amenity_ids'] && !(room_info['amenity_ids'] & [2,3]).empty?}}.to_a:
[#<SearchedItem _id: 5359329d7f11ba034b000006, hotel_id: 127, room_info: [{"price"=>10, "amenity_ids"=>[1, 2]}, {"price"=>160, "amenity_ids"=>nil}]>]
Finished tests in 0.089544s, 33.5031 tests/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.
3 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```